# IP Address for SQL Server / Coding The Connection Into The Client

Tags: sql, encryption

Hello everyone and thank you in advance on your advice:

I have a client where I am coding the SQL server into the application.  But I am hard-coding with 2 layers of encryption heres how it works.

My appconfig file contains the SQL user name and SQL user pw encoded as Base 64.
Before the appconfig file is encoded as base64 I also use a custom char incrementor on every character thats written within my application to "decode"/"encode" the string.

Therefore my SQL connection string looks like this in all my SQL calling methods:  username=decode(UserNameStringValue) password=(PasswordStringValue)

may I have your inputs on storing the SQL Connection string this way?  Safe?  Not Safe? (Yes I do plan on making the application PUBLIC)

Also a little confused on setting the Ip Address of my server.  Right now I can connect to my SQL database using 192.168.1.13:1433 but will this IP address work on a computer that isn't my own??  Which IP do I hardcode into my client application??

Thank you all!

Comment: Is it a .net app?

Comment: Is this application going to run on a network, over the internet?

Comment: yes it is a .net application

Answer (score 0):

[Connection String Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

**Encrypted connection string:**
Whichever method you choose to encrypt your connection string credentials, it'll be important to obfuscate the code that decrypts the connection string.  If you encrypt your connection string and leave your assembly open, someone can go use an application like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and see the code to decrypt (assuming you are using .Net, I'm sure all JIT-compiled languages have a similar issue).

You may want to encrypt the entire connection string to prevent anyone from changing any portion of the connection string.

For example: If your application is going to connect to a database that lives on the internet you will want to encrypt the actual communication (similar to how web browsers and web servers use SSL/TLS to encrypt the line of communication, the same can and should be done with SQL Server communication).  [Here](https://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2018/12/encrypting-adonet-connection-to-sql.html) is more information encrypting ADO.Net connections (assuming you are using .Net).

**IP:**
This will be the server name or IP address for the SQL Server you want your users to connect to.